# Hide popup on drag in kendo kendo-sortable angular

Tags: angular, typescript, kendo-sortable

I'm using **Angular** and **Kendo**, Now I'm meet the problem when I want to hide the popup when drag using **kendo-sortable** as [here](https://stackblitz.com/run/?file=app/app.component.ts) as I draw in the picture[image]

I try a lot of time to hide that but still cannot.

please help me.

Answer (score 1):

a bit late for you, but may help other.
I think kendo team should add a class (or api) for it, but I couldn't find anything.
So here is my workaround which works for me:

I add a style on the active class which hides all active items (these are the dragged one and the popup one) and also add another style for the dragged one to show it.
So only the popup one will be hidden. I found no option to select the popup one as it lacks on properties and styles

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'app-sorttest',
    templateUrl: './sorttest.component.html',
    styles: ['.active { display: none; } .active[kendodraggable] { display: block; }'],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

```html
<kendo-sortable
        [kendoSortableBinding]="items"
        [navigable]="true"
        [animation]="true"
        class="row"
        itemClass="item col-xs-6 col-sm-3"
        activeItemClass="item col-xs-6 col-sm-3 active">
</kendo-sortable>
```

Greets
Niko